# Use FirstOption monoid instance in tuple

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is it possible to convert `(Option[Int], Option[String])` to `(FirstOption[Int], FirstOption[String])`? in a shorter way than `x=> (x._1.first, x._2.first)`?

It seems to me that there should be a way to do this, but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be to use the Bifunctor instance:

```
scala> val t = (Option(1), Option("str"))
t: (Option[Int], Option[java.lang.String]) = (Some(1),Some(str))

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Tags._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Tags._

scala> t.bimap(First, First)
res0: (scalaz.package.@@[Option[Int],scalaz.Tags.First], scalaz.package.@@[Option[java.lang.String],scalaz.Tags.First]) = (Some(1),Some(str))
```

A more idiomatic way (ok, a more generic way: would work for any tuple, tripple, etc.) would probably be using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to turn your tuple into an `HList`, and then apply a natural transformation `Option[A] ~> Option[A] @@ First`. Here's a sketchy implementation of this:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Tags._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Tags._

scala> import shapeless._, Tuples._, Nat._
import shapeless._
import Tuples._
import Nat._

scala> val t = (Option(1), Option("str"))
t: (Option[Int], Option[String]) = (Some(1),Some(str))

scala> object optionToFirstoption extends (Option ~> FirstOption) {
     |   def apply[A](fa: Option[A]): Option[A] @@ First = First(fa)
     | }
defined module optionToFirstoption

scala> t.hlisted.map(optionToFirstoption).tupled
res1: (Option[Int] with scalaz.Tagged[scalaz.Tags.First], Option[String] with scalaz.Tagged[scalaz.Tags.First]) = (Some(1),Some(str))
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd question the use of "more idiomatic" here ;-)

Comment: @MilesSabin Yyeah, a 'more hardcore' will probably describe what's going on better :)

Comment: Alright, one other question: is it possible to make the FirstOption implementation of monoid default without writing the whole `Monoid[Option[T]]`? E.g. 'implicit def firstOptionMonoid[T] = implicitly[Monoid[FirstOption[T]]]` - this obviously does not work but the way I could think of is really verbose (`implicit def firstOptionMonoid[T] = new Monoid[T]{def append(...) = implicitly[Monoid[FirstOption[T]]].append(...); def zero = ...}`)

Comment: @MartinKolinek after asking people at #scalaz@irc, I was able to converge to a solution. You can do that, but it won't be shorter than your 'verbose' version. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/folone/5225060 . Basically, here I import only the `firstOption` instance, and then construct an `Isomorphism` between an `Option` and a `FirstOption`. This allows for derriving the `Monoid` instance from that `Isomorphism`.

Comment: @folone thanks for the extra effort, I had no idea isomorphism existed

Comment: NP, hope I did not make it confusing or something.